# How do I arrange a button/an element in line / with respect to the element above it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

how do I arrange my button so that it is in the center and below the element above it. It has to be synced with the element.

Below is my code:

```css
.position-message {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.background {
    background-color: maroon;
}

.button-shape {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<Title>Click to get quotes</title>

<body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row-xs-6">
                <div class="well position-message">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="button-shape">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please refer to the below snapshot. The button must be in the spot shown but also be responsive to the screen.

[image: Webpage snapshot]

Comment: You are free to choose the answer you want but be aware that you are using bootstrap and you have to correct you markup and use the classes provided by bootstrap. So i advice you to check my answer (am not looking for upvote or accepted answer, but simply for you to understand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the class `text-center` provided by bootstrap to center element inside each div.

You need to also correct the way you are using bootstrap classes. It should be `container` > `row` > `col-*`. There is no `row-xs` or `col` in bootstrap V3.

Also your `title` tag should go inside `head`.

```css
.position-message {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.background {
    background-color: maroon;
}

.button-shape {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Click to get quotes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <div class="well position-message">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                <button type="button" class="button-shape">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
   

    .position-message {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.background {
    background-color: maroon;
}

.button-shape {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.row-xs-6{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<Title>Click to get quotes</title>

<body class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row-xs-6">
                <div class="well position-message">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="button-shape">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you seen your own code running ? and what OP requested

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sry i misunderstand the question...i edited my answer according to question

Comment: it's bootstrap, he need to fix his code and not add flex like this

Comment: yes @TemaniAfif is right, and that is why i upvoted his answer, now this answer looks good too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the code is wrong, there is not row-xs ... and there is a class to center element

Comment: @TemaniAfif i think he has custom class with name `row-xs-6` in `css` ? although you can do it by simpy `text-center` i agree

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no i think he simply using bootstrap classe wrong. there is also col .. and he is using container-fluid. So am sure is doing wrong with bootstrap classes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table;` and   `margin: auto;` to your `.button-shape` class:

```
 .button-shape {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: he's using bootrap, so he need to correct his code and use predefined classes